# How can I hide the Box SimpleShare preferences pane when the app starts?

Tags: applescript

I have set the *Box SimpleShare* app to start at login, but the app launches its preferences pane right after it loads its icon in the menu bar. Setting it to start in “hidden” mode in  *System Preferences > Users & Goups > Login Items* doesn’t change that behavior.

I tried to create an AppleScript, saved as an app, to launch the *Box SimpleShare* app at login and hide the pref pane, but it doesn’t work as expected.

```
set tApp to "Box SimpleShare"
tell application tApp to launch
tell application "System Events"
    set visible of process "Box SimpleShare" to false
end tell
```

This launches the app but it does not close the *Box SimpleShare* preferences pane. What would be the proper code to do that?

[image: Screenshot of the preferences window]

Comment: This might sound like a silly question, but humor me: have you tried closing the preferences window before quitting the application? Maybe you are just being bitten by Lion’s Resume function…

Comment: I see your point, kopi

Comment: I see your point, kopi It has never been open before shutting down the machine. That's my point. Every day I have to close it manually to start working in a clean desktop. There isn't even a Saved Application State folder for it. Thank you.

Comment: downloaded and tried it myself – a persistent little pest indeed (I can only imagine the box people consider it crucial you see your account data every time you start the app). Answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Box’s preference window is a particularly persistent one – not only does it insist on displaying every time the application is launched, it will re-open if closed before the app has finished its initialization sequence! However, with some GUI Scripting, it **is** possible to get rid of it. The following code will launch the application, wait for the preferences window to pop up and close it after a short delay (so it can complete its initialization sequence):

```
property timeOutMax : 5
property timeOutStep : 1
property boxLoadDelay : 2

set boxApp to "Box SimpleShare"
tell application boxApp to launch
set timeOutCounter to 0
tell application "System Events"
    tell process boxApp
        repeat while (window 1 of it exists) is false and timeOutCounter is less than timeOutMax
            delay timeOutStep
            set timeOutCounter to timeOutCounter + timeOutStep
        end repeat
        if window 1 of it exists then
            delay boxLoadDelay
            click (button 1 of window 1 of it)
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

If the window re-opens on your system, set a higher value for `boxLoadDelay`. Also, if the script times out before the application has loaded, adjust the value for `timeOutMax` (and possibly for `timeOutStep` if you have to select a much higher timeout threshold).

Comment: Amazing! This works beautifully: Thank you very much for helping me to get rid of that pesky window: I just had to adjust the boxLoadDelay to 3  :-)

tell kopischke to have A
 set A to "Wonderful Day"

    end tell